# Is `if(CONSTANT) { ... }` optimized in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, optimization, constants

Do modern compilers optimize a piece of code like `if(CONSTANT) { ... }`, where `CONSTANT` is a literal, template argument, `const` variable or `constexpr` variable? Do they remove the whole `if(0) { ... }` expression or "throw out" the `if(1)` part in `if(1) { ... }`?

Comment: Check the assembly output with the `if(constant)` and check the output without it. As far as I know a lot of compilers will make this type of optimization with the optimization level set high enough, if CONSTANT is truly a constant.

Comment: Being a `const` variable doesn't necessarily mean the compiler knows the value.

Comment: It depends on the compiler and all flags. Usually it will be removed, if optimization is on and the "debugging support" is off. Of course assuming it is a real compile-time constant.

Comment: @shuttle87 That's an idea, but note that not all C/C++ programmers (especially beginners) can read assembly.

Comment: Modern compilers do all optimizations their authors found time to teach them, which preserve the semantics of correct programs, where those same authors didn't think them too dangerous.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Thanks. The accepted *answer* is helpful. But note that the only "question part" in that question is "how does the compiler optimize a method that is declared const vs one that isn't". I can't see how my question duplicates that one.

Comment: [Simple live demo](http://ideone.com/KzvJfQ)

Comment: @KerrekSB That's an interesting trick.

Comment: cubuspl42 - I agree that's not the best 'duplicate' reference, but still far more useful than this [more-of-a-duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995659/can-modern-compilers-optimize-constant-expressions-where-the-expression-is-deriv). Strangely, I coulnd't find any better ones (still, I know they exist, this question is quite common), so I linked the one that gives most useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not guaranteed but most compilers of good quality will do it.

C99 Rationale says in 6.4.9:

> ```
> if (0) {
>  /* code to be excluded */
> }
> ```
>
> Many modern compilers will generate no code for this if statement.

For example with `gcc` (in C) an assembly dump shows that dead code with either `if (0) .. else` or `if (1) .. else` is optimized out even in `-O0`.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I finally removed the `#if 0` part of the quote to not confuse the reader.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt meant to push work on you, I just left a note for random readers. But many thanks! now that's much clearer and informative!